# UNION / UNION ALL slow or not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, union-all

I have two tables full of customer survey response data. I've been running queries on them separately that return results in less than one second, but if I union them it seems to run forever. After 5+ minutes no results are returned yet and no errors have been thrown, it's still apparently "running" but I can't figure out what it's actually trying to do that could be so complicated.

In essence, my queries that work separately are:

```
SELECT
oldsurveys.column1 as [something1],
oldsurveys.column2 as [something2],
oldsurveys.column3 as [something3],
'staticvalue1' as [something4],
oldsurveys.column5 as [something5]
FROM
database1.dbo.table1 oldsurveys
WHERE
oldsurveys.column1 = 'something'
AND oldsurveys.column2 >= '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
ORDER BY [something2], [something1]

SELECT
newsurveys.column1 as [something1],
newsurveys.column2 as [something2],
newsurveys.column3 as [something3],
newsurveys.column4 as [something4],
'staticvalue2' as [something5]
FROM
database2.dbo.table1 newsurveys
WHERE
newsurveys.column1 = 'something'
AND newsurveys.column2 >= '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
ORDER BY [something2], [something1]
```

If I run this, I get two tables of data returned almost instantly. If I add `UNION ALL` between the two select statements, comment out the first `ORDER BY` and try running again it just runs and runs and runs, no results...

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Would the tables being in different databases cause this, and if so, is there a workaround?

Comment: What if you remove the ordering from both of them?

Comment: If I remove the `ORDER BY` clause altogether then it pulls all of the results for the first select statement pretty quickly, then nothing comes in from the second select statement (same issue with it just running indefinitely).

Comment: Don't think I can get the execution plan, when I try to turn it on I get an error message - "Msg 262, Level 14, State 4, Line 1
SHOWPLAN permission denied in database 'Database2'."

Comment: I really think you should convert your date fields to varchar Convert(varchar,newsurveys.column2,112)>='20140101', pelase try it.

Comment: Interesting... I converted the fields as you suggested and it at least finished the query this time (though I'm not sure if that might be because of the time of day - many fewer requests go to the server in the late afternoon here). It took about 10 minutes to complete, which I can live with. I'm still puzzled why it would take so long compared to the separate queries though.

Comment: Converting something in where clause is expensive, the query will ignore indexes, built on column2. Instead of converting the fileld, you should cast the string to date or whatever type the column2 is. What indexes do you have on column1 and column2?

Answer (score 1):

Without an execution plan, getting the exact cause of your performance problem is nearly impossible. Here's one *possible* explanation for this behaviour:

- you've got indices on `[something2]` and `[something1]` for both tables
- when you query each table separately, SQL Server uses the indices
- when you `UNION ALL` both queries, SQL Server could theoretically use each index to sort the results of the subquery, but it cannot use the index to sort the complete result set, so it has to sort the complete result set

BTW, (since you mentioned both in your title but only one in your post body), there's a *huge* difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL` - the former might perform much worse, since it has to remove duplicates from the result set.

Comment: `[something2]` is the primary key in each database, `[something1]` is a datetime. Not sure if either or both of those are indexed. Since both databases are being populated by surveys taken by different customers there should not be any duplicates, so I've been testing mostly with `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` (though in my frustration I have tried both to see if it would make any difference). I'm taking a total of 10 columns and there are ~30,600 results in query1 and ~260 in query2, it doesn't seem like it should be hard to sort that many rows even if it's doing it all without an index. :s